# Center view to another in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have two views that I want to **center vertically** in a RelativeLayout.

Is there a way to do this without using gravity/layout_gravity ?[image]

**My problem behind this question :**

I need to do a layout with several squares and under each one a TextView. The main problem is that the TextViews must overlap. Only one TextView will be visible at a time. Each TextView has a different lengh.

I started with a RelativeLayout but encountred the previous problem. And I can't group the views 2 per 2 because I need to set a layout_toRightOf of the previous square.

[image]

**Current layout :**

For the moment, I have set a magic number in layout_marginLeft for each square (to the border of the parent view) but it isn't clean at all.

[image]

*Thanks*

Comment: Could you show your layout right now?

Comment: I have added the picture in the question.
For the moment, I have set a magic number in layout_marginLeft for each square (to the border of the parent view) but it isn't clean at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I kept the the layout_marginLeft but I put the values in my res/values/dimens.xml, it is cleaner and I can have a dimens.xml per screen dimension.
A trick is to set the width of the textViews deliberately big so it won't depend on the strings lenght.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to center something into a `RelativeLayout`
You can use `android:layout_below="@id/your_first_view"` to put your second `View` below the first !
If you want to do more complex stuff you may separate your different Views and store the into new `LinearLayout` that you set to horizontal or vertical depending on your needs.
Another trick can be to create empty Views with small height or width and that can help you to position thing around them !
This combined to the `toRightOf` `toLeftOf` stuff will do what you want

Comment: I have several squares so I can't center them all in the middle of the global RelativeLayout.

Comment: I will try the empty views.

Comment: Hm, it is not very conclusive. So I have listed 4 empty views horizontaly and have put my objects (the 2 views) under each one. However, I faced the same problem, i can't center my objects under the  empty views.

Comment: Try do to something like this : YourElement1 | EmptyView | YourElement2 | ....., and put the whole stuff in a LinearLayout with gravity="center" attribute ! Setting the width of the EmptyView to 1dp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58254/discussion-between-helix-and-bumblebeez).